# Draw over other app service reopens itself after closing

Tags: android, android-service, floating, forceclose

I would like to apologize if this is somehow a repeated question that has been answered. I have tried the solutions I was able to find here and still not able to do the thing I need.

I am still trying to learn programming with android system and currently trying to do something like the chat bubble that draws over other app. From learning on this site, I was able to do it by opening an intent, but I have not been able to find a way to close the app completely--even after swiping it to close after pressing the home key for a short period of time, the app will automatically reopens itself. Let me try to explain it better with what I am doing.

### In manifest:

I have

and these:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Play"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>


<service
        android:name="com.example.play.MainClass"
        android:exported="true" />
```

### In Play.java

```
public class Play extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent svc = new Intent(this, MainClass.class);
        startService(svc);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

}
```

### In MainClass.java

I am using this

```
public class MainClass extends Service {
.......
}
```

as well as using

```
private WindowManager wm;
```

and do the codes using the wm to display the chat bubble i need.

I have been trying to search how to close android app programmatically and phrases like that and I found that many answers include doing:
System.exit(0);
or
finish();
or 
Process.killProcess(int pid)

But then again, I am not able to close my app completely--it runs again by itself after around 10-20seconds. I am thinking it is because I am using 'Service' so I am not able to close the app completely.

I am looking forward to any of your kind reply and patience.

I apologize in advance for if this is still answered somewhere that I was not able to find it.

Thank you very much.